# Oracle Xe not working

Tags: oracle

I am not able to connect the oracle Xe from sql developer. I am getting error "Status : failure: IO Error: The  Network Adaptor could not establish the connection."

I tried to configure the listener but could not configure correct listener. Could you please help me how to add the correct listener.

tnsname.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = somsuman-VirtualBox)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

listner.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
)

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = somsuman-VirtualBox)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: What is the complete database version? what is your OS? What does `lsnrctl status` say?

Comment: Are you trying to connect within the virtual box (from the HOST value), or from the host operating system? What is your connection string?

Comment: lsnrctl statusListener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/somsuman-VirtualBox/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=somsuman-VirtualBox)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
somsuman@somsuman-VirtualBox:/u01/

Comment: i am trying to connect with below details Hostname:192.168.56.101 Port:1521 service name: XE Username: system in sql developer

Comment: Ubantu 14 is the OS and oracle XE 11g is the DB

Comment: That didn't answer the first part of my question. Are you running SQL Developer on the virtual host, or on the real host? Which is Ubuntu, and what is the other OS? What does somsuman-VirtualBox resolve to? Is there a firewall running on the virtual host, and if so have you opened up port 1521?

Comment: I am running the SQL developer in real Host. Oracle xe is running in Ubuntu and SQL developer is running in mac os. There is no firewall running on the Ubuntu Hose. I can do ssh from mac os to Ubuntu but when I try the connect SQL developer with basic authentication like username, password, host port and service name I am not able to connect.

Comment: Can you telnet to from Mac to Ubuntu, on default port 23 and SQL\*Net port 1521, to see if it connects or is rejected/times out? If you can get to port 22 (ssh) but not port 23 and/or 1521 that would still sound like a firewall issue. Something else to check is whether the listener is on the right IP - so what somsuman-VirtualBox resolves to might be important. But you'd get a different error (no listener) if that was the only problem.